# Analzying a table of 1's and 0's using methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I can not get the program to compile correctly. I trying to create a table of random of 1's and 0's. They size of the array is determined by the user and the program is supposed to analyze the above table and print another table counting the numbers of 1's in a row.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework {

 public static void scanInfo()
 {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");    
int rows = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter number of columns: "); 
int columns = input.nextInt();

int[][] nums = new int[rows][columns];            

 static int[][] sample = nums;

}
   static int[][] results = new int[4][5];
   static int goodData = 1;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      analyzeTable();
      printTable(results);
   } 

   static void analyzeTable() {
      int row=0;
      while (row < sample.length) {
         analyzeRow(row);
         row++;
      }
   }

   static void analyzeRow(int row) {
      int xCol = 0;
      int rCount = 0;
      while (xCol < sample[row].length) {
         rCount = analyzeCell(row,xCol);
         results[row][xCol] = rCount; // instead of print
         xCol++;
      }
   }

   static int analyzeCell(int row, int col) {
      int xCol = col;   // varies in the loop
      int runCount = 0;  // initialize counter
      int rowLen = sample[row].length;   // shorthand
      int hereData = sample[row][xCol];  // shorthand
      while (hereData == goodData && xCol < rowLen) {
         runCount++;
         xCol++;
         if (xCol < rowLen) { hereData = sample[row][xCol];} 
      }
      return runCount;
   }

  /*   Start Print Stuff */
  public static void printTable(int[][] aTable ) {
    for (int[] row : aTable) {
      printRow(row);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public static void printRow(int[] aRow) {
    for (int cell  : aRow) {
      System.out.printf("%d ", cell);
    }
  }
}
  /*   End Print Stuff */
```

Comment: Your IDE will highlight the error for you, so why do you ask here?

Comment: Interesting.. A static variable declaration in a static method. Also, does `scanInfo()` ever get invoked?

Comment: also, making a variable inside a method will NOT make it visible for the other methods, even if you put the "static" keyword in front of it.

Comment: @MightyPork, right, unlike C/C++.

Comment: voting for close - " you have already asked this question 3 times "

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of errors, but this should get you started.

Outside of any method, put

```
static int[][] nums = null;            
static int[][] sample = null;
```

And then inside `scanInfo`, change the lines to

```
nums = new int[rows][columns];
sample = nums;
```

Also, call `scanInfo()` from `main()`.